# Simple search and replace items from a SharePoint list using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

The script works fine replacing from "title" column with "Single line of text" but with "Custom Column Name" and "Multiple lines of text" it fails?

**Title** - Single line of text
**URLLInk** - Multiple lines of text

**WORKS**

`$item["Title"] = $item["Title"].Replace("72PRD","PRD")`

**FAILS**

`$item["URLLInk"] = $item["URLLInk"].Replace("72PRD","PRD")`

This is the error message sent back to PS:

> ```
> At D:\ps\ReplaceLinks1.ps1:10 char:27
> + $value = $item["URLLink"] if($value -Contains "72PRD") {
> +                           ~~
> Unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
> ```

Tried the script above, and numerous variations

Basic Search and Replace for part of URL in SharePoint List Column that is just set as Multiple lines of text using SP Powershell

```
**THIS WORKED!!!!**

#MS testing script
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://ADDRESS
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

if($list = $web.Lists.TryGetList('LIST')){

    foreach ($item in $list.Items){
        $item['COLUMN-NAME'] = $item['COLUMN-NAME'] -replace 'TEXT', 'TEXT'
        $item.SystemUpdate()
    }

    Write-Host 'Updated values in the list items are' -fore green
    foreach ($item in $list.Items){
        $item['LinkData']
    }

}else{
    Write-Host '"LIST" not found' -fore red
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that your `if` statement should not be there. Move it down one line with Enter or put a semi-colon (;) in between.

Comment: I just posted code and clean version thanks for responding

Comment: The error does not reflect the code. There is no `$value = $item["URLLink"]`..

Comment: Can you possibly paste a solution you may have?

Comment: No, because the code you show cannot possibly return that particular error message. You may however try a Regex `-replace` like `$item["URLLInk"] = $item["URLLInk"] -replace "72PRD", "PRD"`

Comment: What's the Multiple lines of text format? Plain text/rich text/enhanced rich text, as I did simple test in my local, the script is working, it may related to your filed value also, so you may share your sample data.